# Обновление виджета android

Tags: android-sdk, android

На сайте [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) написано, что метод `onUpdate` вызывается по истечению `updatePeriodMillis`. Но когда я пишу в методе `onUpdate`, например, `Log.e("tag", "update")`, он пишет в лог только при запуске виджета.

Почему так?

Не, все в порядке. `updatePeriodMillis` установил меньше, чем полчаса

Comment: так а ты период задаешь?

Comment: да, задаю.

Comment: сделай версию апи 1.5

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем так. В [документации сказано](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis), что виджет будет апдейтиться не чаще чем 1 раз в пол-часа, даже если `updatePeriodMillis` меньше. Соотв, подожди пол-часа, апдейт придет. Если хочешь чаще - апдейть вручную при помощи [AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)